# simple integration problem wrt y

Tags: integration

We have to find the area bounded by the region y=$e^x$ , $x=0$ and $y=e$. It has used integration wrt y.

I understand the area = $\int_1^e \ln y \,dy$. But fail to understand how $\int_1^e \ln y \,dy=\int_1^e \ln(e+1-y)\,dy$.

I can integrate

$\int_1^e \ln(e+1-y)\, dy$, taking  e+1-y = t , we get -dy = dt

=-$\int_e^1 \ln t\, dt$ , (here the upper and lower bounded value changed wrt t)

=$\int_1^e \ln t\, dt$

But how is this equal to $\int_1^e \ln y \,dy$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$t$ is just a variable used for the integration, so we have $$\int_{1}^{e}f(t)dt=\int_{1}^{e}f(y)dy=\int_{1}^{e}f(z)dz=\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

---

Evaluating both sides by integrating by parts you can see that they are in fact the same.

$$\int_{1}^{e}\ln(t)dt=t\ln(t)\big|_{t=1}^{t=e}-\int_{1}^{e}1dt$$
$$=e-(e-1)=1$$
and $$\int_{1}^{e}\ln(y)dy=y\ln(y)\big|_{y=1}^{y=e}-\int_{1}^{e}1dy$$
$$=e-(e-1)=1.$$

---

Also
$$\int_{1}^{e}\ln(\xi)d\xi=\xi\ln(\xi)\big|_{\xi=1}^{\xi=e}-\int_{1}^{e}1d\xi$$
$$=e-(e-1)=1$$

Comment: Thanks. But would it be the same for general integration i.e if we removed the upper and lower bound values. I don't think so i.e $\int \ln t\, dt \ne \int \ln y\, dy$,  because t= e+1-y. Am I right??

Comment: No, it will not be the same if you removed the upper and lower bound values because we would have a constant of integration and substitution afterwards! Indeed, call $e+1=k=constant$ then : $$\int \ln(y) dy=y\ln(y)-y+c_{1}$$ but $$\int \ln(t) dt=t\ln(t)-t+c_{2}=(k+y)\ln(k+y)-(k+y)+c_{2}$$ which are not the same. Of course since here we computed $\int \ln(t)dt$ and then substituted $t=e+1-y=k-y$ after the integration.